# Fade out (and then in) section after setInterval()

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have three `image` containers which show (different) images on rotation. After a set interval, I'm trying to get that section to fade out nicely, and fade the new image in.

Essentially something like:

- Image shows
- Starts to fade out slowly
- Image changes when it's faded out (so the change isn't visual to the user)
- New image starts to fade in

I've tried to achieve this by setting `position.find(".employeeSlider__image").fadeOut().fadeIn();`, but it's way too fast and looks broken.

See demo here:

```js
$(function() {

  var left = $('.employeeSlider__left');
  var mid = $('.employeeSlider__middle');
  var right = $('.employeeSlider__right');
  var images = [];

  // push images to array
  $('.employeeSlider__images').each(function() {
    var src = $(this).attr('src');
    images.push(src);
  });

  /***********/
  /* HELPERS */
  /***********/

  function changeImage(position) {
    var currentLeft = left.find('.employeeSlider__image').attr('src');
    var currentMid = mid.find('.employeeSlider__image').attr('src');
    var currentRight = right.find('.employeeSlider__image').attr('src');
    var floor = images.length - 1;

    var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * (floor - 0 + 1)) + 0;
    var randomIndexPlus = randomIndex + 1;
    var randomIndexMinus = randomIndex - 1;

    //$(".employeeSlider__image").fadeOut(400, function() {
    if (images[randomIndex] != currentRight && images[randomIndex] != currentMid && images[randomIndex] != currentLeft) {
      position.find('.employeeSlider__image').attr('src', images[randomIndex]);
    } else if (images[randomIndexPlus] != currentRight && images[randomIndexPlus] != currentMid && images[randomIndexPlus] != currentLeft) {
      position.find('.employeeSlider__image').attr('src', images[randomIndexPlus]);
    } else if (images[randomIndexMinus] != currentRight && images[randomIndexMinus] != currentMid && images[randomIndexMinus] != currentLeft) {
      position.find('.employeeSlider__image').attr('src', images[randomIndexMinus]);
    } else {
      position.find('.employeeSlider__image').attr('src', images[0]);
    }
    //}).fadeIn(400);
    /* position.find(".employeeSlider__image").fadeOut().fadeIn() */
    ;

  }

  /*****************/
  /* CHANGE IMAGES */
  /*****************/

  // left image
  setInterval(function() {
    changeImage(left);
  }, 3800);

  // middle image
  setTimeout(function() {
    setInterval(function() {
      changeImage(mid);
    }, 4000);
  }, 1000);

  // right image
  setTimeout(function() {
    setInterval(function() {
      changeImage(right);
    }, 4200);
  }, 2000);


});
```

```css
section {
  background: lightblue;
}

.employeeSlider {
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 520px;
}

.employeeSlider__left,
.employeeSlider__middle,
.employeeSlider__right {
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 10px solid #ffffff;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
}

.employeeSlider__left img,
.employeeSlider__middle img,
.employeeSlider__right img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -o-object-fit: cover;
  object-fit: cover;
  -o-object-position: center;
  object-position: center;
}

.employeeSlider__left {
  width: 182px;
  height: 182px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 40px;
  z-index: 2;
}

.employeeSlider__middle {
  width: 407px;
  height: 417px;
  top: 58px;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.employeeSlider__right {
  width: 222px;
  height: 222px;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 3;
}

.employeeImages {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.9.1/gsap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.9.1/ScrollTrigger.min.js"></script>


<section class="section">

  <div class="employeeSlider">
    <div class="employeeSlider__left">
      <img class="employeeSlider__image" src="" alt="" loading="disabled">
    </div>
    <div class="employeeSlider__middle">
      <img class="employeeSlider__image" src="" alt="" loading="disabled">
    </div>
    <div class="employeeSlider__right">
      <img class="employeeSlider__image" src="" alt="" loading="disabled">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="employeeImages">
    <img class="employeeSlider__images" src="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/2270223/2022/Leadership%20Profile%20Shots/Silverfin_Leadership_Joris_VanDerGutch.jpg" alt="Silverfin_Leadership_Joris_VanDerGutch" loading="lazy">
    <img class="employeeSlider__images" src="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/2270223/2022/Leadership%20Profile%20Shots/Silverfin_Leadership_Tim_Vandecasteele.jpg" alt="Silverfin_Leadership_Tim_Vandecasteele" loading="lazy">
    <img class="employeeSlider__images" src="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hub/2270223/hubfs/2022/Leadership%20Profile%20Shots/Silverfin_Leadership_Nikolas_Savander.jpg?width=480&amp;height=600&amp;name=Silverfin_Leadership_Nikolas_Savander.jpg" alt="Silverfin_Leadership_Nikolas_Savander"
      loading="lazy">
    <img class="employeeSlider__images" src="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/2270223/2022/Leadership%20Profile%20Shots/Silverfin_Leadership_Natalie_Lamb.jpg" alt="Silverfin_Leadership_Natalie_Lamb" loading="lazy">
    <img class="employeeSlider__images" src="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/2270223/2022/Leadership%20Profile%20Shots/Silverfin_Leadership_Stuart_Handley.jpg" alt="Silverfin_Leadership_Stuart_Handley" loading="lazy">
    <img class="employeeSlider__images" src="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/2270223/2022/Leadership%20Profile%20Shots/Silverfin_Leadership_Domien_Claeys.jpg" alt="Silverfin_Leadership_Domien_Claeys" loading="lazy">
    <img class="employeeSlider__images" src="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/2270223/2022/Leadership%20Profile%20Shots/Silverfin_Leadership_Tom_Libbrecht.jpg" alt="Silverfin_Leadership_Tom_Libbrecht" loading="lazy">
    <img class="employeeSlider__images" src="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/2270223/2022/Leadership%20Profile%20Shots/Silverfin_Leadership_Stefaan_Arryn.jpg" alt="Silverfin_Leadership_Stefaan_Arryn" loading="lazy">
    <img class="employeeSlider__images" src="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/2270223/2022/Leadership%20Profile%20Shots/Silverfin_Leadership_Steve_Wozniak.jpg" alt="Silverfin_Leadership_Steve_Wozniak" loading="lazy">
    <img class="employeeSlider__images" src="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/2270223/2022/Leadership%20Profile%20Shots/Silverfin_Leadership_Louis_Verbeke.jpg" alt="Silverfin_Leadership_Louis_Verbeke" loading="lazy">
  </div>

</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

FadeOut documentation: https://api.jquery.com/fadeout/

`fadeOut` takes 2 parameters - duration and a callback. So just set it to slower and call `fadeIn` on the second element;

```
function fadeImages($first, $second){
    $first.fadeOut(1000, () => $second.fadeIn(1000));
}
```

Working example:

```js
/////////////////scripts///////////////////////

function fadeSquares($el1, $el2){
  $el1.fadeOut(2000, ()=>{
    $el2.fadeIn(2000);
  });
}

/////////////////execute///////////////////////

let $el1 = $('#red');
let $el2 = $('#blue');

fadeSquares($el1, $el2);
```

```css
.square {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

#red {
  background-color: red;
}

#blue {
  background-color: blue;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='wrapper'>
  <div id='red' class='square'>a red square</div>
  <div id='blue' class='square'>a blue square</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Dropout, could you show me your approach in a working demo using my demo please? I have previously tried wrapping my function around `$(".employeeSlider__image").fadeOut(400, function() { ... }).fadeIn(400);` but it didn't have the desired effect (I have updated my Q to showcase)

Comment: @Freddy added a snippet to the answer..

Comment: Sorry Dropout, I understand the premise of your solution, but still struggling to see how to implement that alongside my `changeImage()` function, which is being called in a `setInterval` function. If I'm missing some here, could you showcase your solution using my demo?

Comment: @Freddy I've added another example which interchanges images smoothly, if you need an example for the fadeOut/fadeIn. If you have any questions ask there please, but I won't try to incorporate it into your code, that's up to you, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

If you want smooth transitions, then you should run them parallel, i.e. not chain them. The following example uses two containers to interchange pictures that you define in an array of links.

```js
const imgLinks = [
  "https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/images/sunset-quotes-21-1586531574.jpg",
  "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/58/Sunset_2007-1.jpg",
  "https://dynamic-media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-o/17/e0/ce/85/sunset-beach.jpg?w=1200&h=-1&s=1"
];

let it = 0;

function cycleImages($wrapper){
  
  let currentImage = $('#img-wrapper').children()[0];
  let nextImage = prepareNew(imgLinks[it++%imgLinks.length]);
  $wrapper.append(nextImage);
  
  $(currentImage).fadeOut(5000, () => {
    $(currentImage).remove();
    cycleImages($wrapper);
  });
  $(nextImage).fadeIn(5000);
};

function prepareNew(link){
    
  let el = document.createElement('img');
  
  el.style.display = "none";
  el.className = "showcase";
  el.src = link;
  
  return el;
}

cycleImages($('#img-wrapper'));
```

```css
.showcase {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 120px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='img-wrapper'>
  <img src='https://dynamic-media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-o/17/e0/ce/85/sunset-beach.jpg?w=1200&h=-1&s=1' class='showcase' alt='image'/>
</div>
```